# Libreoffice on multiple monitors. Menus open in wrong monitor

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, libreoffice

I am on 12.04 64bit, on 3 monitors, 12.3 fglrx drivers and use Libreoffice 3.5.3 (Ubuntu repositories). The menus of Libreoffice seem to open on the wrong screen. It seems this is an old bug, but i have only noticed it when ubuntu updated Libreoffice to 3.5.3. Previously everything was OK. Every other application behaves OK.

This issues has been reported in bugzilla http://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg18576.html and launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/974900

Does anyone knows if there is a workaround? This bug prevents me from using LibreOffice.

Comment: One workaround is to install lo-menubar so that the menus show on the unity bar and not in the libreoffice windows

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.  Installing lo-menubar doesn't work for me.  The only "fix" I've found so far is to disable my 2nd monitor.

Comment: It looks like the relevant bug in LibreOffice's bugzilla is https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48168

Comment: This is a very annoying bug. Is there something to do to get attention on it? It practically renders LO useless in multi-monitor systems.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm afraid.  Have you added a comment to the LibreOffice bugzilla thread linked to above?  I assume that the more people who comment on a bug, the more likely it is to get noticed by the developers.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no work-around.  What I personally do is either right-click for the context menu, or click a menu(file for example) and don't mouse over any other menus.  In the case of file, just go down into the document viewable space.  Then mouse into the other monitor and use the menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LibreOffice bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48168) hasn't received any official updates for a while so I've done some tinkering.  It turns out that uninstalling "libreoffice-gtk" fixes the menu problem for me (but LibreOffice looks rather ugly without GTK+ integration so this should be viewed as an ugly hack rather than a satisfactory fix... but at least it works)

Comment: Just as you said. A great ugly hack. But thank you very much. If nothing else comes up, the answer and bounty is yours.

Comment: You're welcome!  If you're after a better fix, and if you've got some time to tinker, then it may be worth tinkering with compiling LO from source and trying different compilation options.  The relevant bug report over on Gentoo's bugzilla suggests that re-compiling LO with different compilation options may fix it: https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=408793

Comment: Or perhaps the bug is with GTK+, in which case maybe you could re-compile LO with a different version of GTK+ linked in somehow

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible workarounds:

1. With the menu Slideshow->Slideshow Settings, you can open a dialog which allows you to select the monitor manually at the bottom
2. Since 3.5 the presenter-console has a "exchange screens" quick-button: http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/3.5 To use presenter-console you need to: apt-get install libreoffice-presenter-console

Comment: I am not talking about Impress. This issue happens in all LibreOffice programs, Calc, Writer etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this issue has been now fixed in LO 3.5.5 installed from the PPA.